# Constructor in derived class from MonoBehavior

Tags: unity

So i've got a Part abstract class which inherit from Monobehavior

```
public abstract class Part:MonoBehaviour​
```

And then I've a class frame which inherit from Part class

```
public class Frame: Part
{
    public Frame(string partId) {​
    this.partId = partId;
    this.name = "Some Random name";​
}
```

​
But on the last line which is `this.name = "Some Random name";`, i got this NullReferenceException.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out a monobehavior script must be attached to a gameobject inorder to be referenced.

Here's the more detailed explanation.

Well, i just guess that the script (and / or the gameobject it's attached to) has been destroyed, or you created the Wait-instance with "new" which would result in the same behaviour since a MonoBehaviour can't live on it's own.

In C# / .NET / Mono instances actually can't be destroyed since they live in a managed memory environment. Objects are destroyed when all references to the object are gone, no longer valid. After that the garbage collector eventually kicks in and removes the object.

However in Unity, since it's core is written in C++, (native) objects can be destroyed on command (with Destroy to be more precise). The Destroy method actually only destroys the object on the c++ side. The managed representation of the object (your MonoBehaviour script) will still be there since the GC can only collect the object when there are no references anymore. That's why Unity actually "fakes" that the reference is null when the object has lost it's native counterpart.

If you use the "new" keyword to create an instance of a MonoBehaviour derived class the instance doesn't have a native counterpart and will always pretend to be null. If you want to create an instance at runtime it has to be attached to a gameobject. This is done with

[Constructor in derived class from MonoBehavior](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/124832/cant-access-the-name-field-of-custom-class-nullreferenceexception-unity3d#)

Answer (score 1):

It's not allowed to have constructor in MonoBehaviour and derived class. Use Awake, Start instead.

In constructor unity fields are not deserialized yet, so it's not reliable to use that data. So unity provides it's methods mentioned earlier which is executed after construction and deserialization phases.

Comment: But the code under Frame is all successfully executed until this.name, which i assume is a problem from .name

Comment: updated my answer, name is not initalised yet in constructor